# I have a SharePoint Hosted app ready. How to host it in the sharepoint store?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have a SharePoint Hosted App ready and i'm looking to host it in SharePoint Store. I have came across many sites and i'm not sure which one should i proceed with. People say to check with sellers Dashboard. But, when i tried with Sellers Dashboard, it was taking me to Windows Apps. Can any of you provide me the exact Url to proceed with ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you check the official guideline.

https://dev.office.com/officestore/docs/submit-to-the-office-store